# Error when trying to copy directory content with rsync inside a shell script

Tags: bash, rsync, scp

I want to copy the content of `"src/main/resources/"` to my remote servers. This folder contains several `*properties` files.

The following command executes without any problem in bash and zsh:

```
rsync -av "src/main/resources/*" "azureuser@s1.cloudapp.net:/home/azureuser"
```

However, when executing such command inside a shell script I'm getting the following error. I think its due to the `*` expansion in the shell.

```
rsync: link_stat "/home/marcos/Desenvolvimento/Java/EXT-Hyuga/src/main/resources/*" failed: No such file or directory (2)
```

How can I fix this issue?

Shell Script Content:

```
#!/bin/bash

# server array
declare -a deployinstances=("s1" "s2" "s3" "s4")

## looping trough deploy instances
for di in "${deployinstances[@]}"
do
   rsync -av "src/main/resources/*" "azureuser@$di.cloudapp.net:/home/azureuser"
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first command, the one you have run directly in command line would not work either.

In `bash` (and all other shells), filename generation (AKA pathname expansion or glob expansion) will not take place when the tokens (e.g. `*`, `?`, `[]`) are put inside quotes (double and single) as the quote removal is done by shell after pathname expansion for any word, so the word is treated literally then.

So you need to keep `*` outside of quotes:

```
rsync -av src/main/resources/* azureuser@"$di".cloudapp.net:/home/azureuser/
```

I have not used any quotes here in any pathname, because unless you have spaces in the path you don't need quotes around a path.